# SQLitedatabase Update Function Not Finding Row ID?

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I'm trying to update a user's "CashStack" when that user clicks to use their in game currency. So far I've found that the user's ID should be 6 but when I try to use this hard coded value in my database update function I'm getting a `null` object reference error. Can anyone help me understand why this value is incorrect? I'm working in Android Studio and using SQLite.

Functions being used: `public void updateCashStack(int newCashStack){..}` (see below), `fiveDollar.setOnClickListener(..)`

How I'm finding ID number:

```
int lastID = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    if(userIDs[i] != 0) {
        lastID = userIDs[i];
        Toast.makeText(ChoosePokerStyle.this, "User ID = " + lastID, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show( );
    }
}
```

What shows when I run app:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8f0yl.jpg]

Database Code:

```
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "rockfinn.db";
private SQLiteDatabase db;
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "user_data";
public static final String COL1 = "ID";
public static final String COL2 = "NICKNAME";
public static final String COL3 = "CASHSTACK";

public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String createTable = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            "NICKNAME TEXT, " +
            "CASHSTACK INT)";
    db.execSQL(createTable);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
}

public boolean addData(String nickname) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL2, nickname);
    contentValues.put(COL3, 1000);

    long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);

    if(result == -1) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}

public void updateCashStack(int newCashStack)
{
    try
    {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COL3, newCashStack);
        String whereClause = "id = ?";
        db.update(TABLE_NAME, values, whereClause, new String[] {"6"});
        //db.setTransactionSuccessful();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("Error in transaction", "Error", e);
    }
    finally
    {
      // db.endTransaction();
    }
}

public Cursor getListContents() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor data = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME, null);
    return data;
}
```

}

`fiveDollar.setOnClickListener` code:

```
fiveDollar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener( ) {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
       int five = 5;
       int cashStackAsInt = Integer.parseInt(cashStack);
       cashStackAsInt = cashStackAsInt - five;
       userCashStackPrompt.setText(Integer.toString(cashStackAsInt));
       myDB.updateCashStack(cashStackAsInt);
       Toast.makeText(ChoosePokerStyle.this, "You have bet $5", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show( );
    }
}
```

Comment: Add a breakpoint to line `db.update(TABLE_NAME, values, whereClause, new String[] {"6"});` in the database code. Run in debug mode (e.g. click green bug)). When debug window appears inspect the variables. At a guess **db** is null. If so you need to ensure that **myDB** has been instantiated and that the acll is within the scope of **myDB**. For more in depth details about debugging/breakpoints refer to [Debug your app](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug)

Comment: Yay!! this worked!! thank you so much i will utilize debug mode more in my future programminggg!

Comment: That's good. I've added the above as answer. Could you please tick this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In your table there is no column titled `id`. It should be `ID`. Try like below:

```
whereClause = "ID = ?";
```

Comment: @BickeringVmax, Did you check this?

Answer (score 0):

The syntax in SQL is not case sensitive, but in your database define column `String COL1 = "ID";` it don't match with `String whereClause = "id = ?";`

You can use `String whereClause = COL1 + " = ?";` or `String whereClause = "ID = ?";`

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

> I'm getting a null object reference error.

The most likely cause is that an in-scope instantiated instance of myDB doesn't exist.

You can check this by placing a breakpoint on the line

```
db.update(TABLE_NAME, values, whereClause, new String[] {"6"});
```

in **DatabaseHelper.java**.

Then run in debug mode (e.g. click green bug)). 
When debug window appears inspect the variables.

At a guess **db** is null. If so you need to ensure that **myDB** has been instantiated and that the call is within the scope of **myDB** (e.g. declare **myDB** at the class level and instantiate it in the **onCreate** method of an activity or the equivalent for a fragment).

You may wish to refer to [Debug your app](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug) for more info on Debugging.